# Getting the property of selected element in AngularJS select

Tags: angularjs

I have simple question for AngularJS select. I'm creating select tag using array from  objects.

```
<select data-ng-model="selectedPipeLine" name="selectedPipeLine" required="required" data-ng-options="obj.id as obj.name for obj in pipeLinesList">
    </select>
    {{selectedPipeLine}}
```

When user selected from this select the selected id `obj.id` is displayed near to select. 
But the objects into array have other properties. How I can display other property?
 `{{pipeLinesList[selectedPipeLine]}}` don't working.

I would appreciate any ideas and tips.

Here is jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/zono/6bpNY/2/

I want to get value of `otherProperty`.

Best Regards.

Comment: Can you create a basic fiddle with your attempt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, I think you could change your expression like this:

```
data-ng-options="obj.name for obj in pipeLinesList"
```

Your `selectedPipeLine` in this case is **not** the `id`, but **the reference to the currently selected object** => you can freely access any properties of this object. Like this:

```
<select data-ng-model="selectedPipeLine" name="selectedPipeLine" required="required" data-ng-options="obj.name for obj in pipeLinesList">
</select>

{{selectedPipeLine.id}}
{{selectedPipeLine.otherProperty}}
```

[Your updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6bpNY/3/)